# ajax don't retrieve fully php request response

Tags: ajax

I'm facing challenge with ajax response in my code:

```
//  ********* PHP code (LoadData.php) ****************
<?php 
include 'Connexion.php';

$requete="SELECT id, pkuid, province, nom, prenom, tel, nom_mammifere, qte_male, qte_femell, ST_AsGeoJSON(geom, 5) as geom FROM mammiferes ORDER BY nom";
    
$Connection = Connexion::getInstance()->getDB();
$res = $Connection->prepare($requete);
$res->execute();

$features=[];
while($row = $res->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $feature =["type"=> "Feature"];
    $feature["geometry"] = json_decode($row["geom"]);

    unset($row["geom"]);
    
    $feature["properties"]=$row;
    $features[]=$feature;
    //array_push($features, $feature);
 }

$featureCollection = ["type"=>"FeatureCollection", "features"=>$features];              
echo json_encode($featureCollection);
?>
```

This works fine and retrieve data using such url: localhost/myproject/loadData.php
Now I want to send the output of this file in my javascript file using ajax. Below is my ajax call:

> ```
> $.ajax({
> url:'loadData.php',
> type:'POST',    
> success:function(response){ 
>     alert(response);
> },
> error:function(xhr, status, error){
>         console.log(xhr);
>         console.log(status);
>         console.log(error);
>     }
>  });
> ```

this retrieve just a part of the php result (for example 75 of 3500 rows) of this result is sometime not a valid json (jsonlint.com).

What is going wrong?